# Work from first character to last in variable (bash)

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'm trying to make my bash script process the first character in a variable and work until it reaches the last. Here's what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo Word?
read -r -p '' foo
# $foo is set to 'Antarctica' by user.

wordlength=${#foo}
$wordlength says 10, so start on character 1.
'A' is first letter received in $foo, so echo '{a,A}'
'n' is second letter received in $foo, so echo '{n,N}'
't' is third letter received in $foo, so echo '{t,T}'
'a' is fourth letter received in $foo, so echo '{a,A}'
........
'i' is eighth letter received in $foo, so echo '{i,I}'
'c' is ninth letter received in $foo, so echo '{c,C}'
'a' is tenth letter received in $foo, so echo '{a,A}'
```

And here's what it would look like on the user's end:

```
Word?
```

*Antarctica*

```
{a,A}{n,N}{t,T}{a,A}{r,R}{c,C}{t,T}{i,I}{c,C}{a,A}
```

Which is what it would output exactly. Anyone know how to do this?

---

Edit: I guess they could be linked like this?
    $wordlength is 10, so begin with 1 and go to 10.

```
if 1st letter of $foo is A, echo '{a,A}'
if 2st letter of $foo is n, echo '{n,N}'
.....
```

Comment: Can you please clarify?

Comment: The user would enter a word, and the script would echo corresponding text for each letter in order.

Comment: Can you explain how the "A" in Antartica is mapped to 0.0 ? Similarly for other characters...

Comment: `{0.0}` is just a sample text string. It doesn't mean anything. I am wondering how to map strings of text to characters.

Comment: There, edited it to make it much simpler as to what I want to do. Don't know why I didn't specify before.

Comment: `echo Antarctica | perl -p -e 's/([[:alpha:]])/{\L$1\E,\U$1\E}/g'`  outputs the following:  `{a,A}{n,N}{t,T}{a,A}{r,R}{c,C}{t,T}{i,I}{c,C}{a,A}`

Answer (score 4):

To iterate on each character of a string in `ksh93` or `bash` or `zsh`:

```
string=whatever
for ((i = 0; i < ${#string}; i++)); do
   printf '%s\n' "Character $((i + 1)): ${string: i:1}"
done
```

In `zsh` (same in `yash` except that `yash` doesn't support the `for ((...))` syntax), see also:

```
for ((i = 1; i <= ${#string}; i++)); do
   printf '%s\n' "Character $i: $string[i]"
done
```

Or using the `s` (for split) *parameter expansion flag* with the empty string as the separator:

```
for c (${(s"")string}) something with "$c"
```

For mapping character to string, you'd use either a `case` construct like:

```
case $c in
  (A) s='{O.O}';;
  (a) s='{q-p}';;
  ...
esac
```

Or an associative array:

- `zsh`:

  ```
  typeset -A map
  map=(
    A  '{O.O}'
    a  '{q-p}'
    ...
  )
  s=$map[$c]
  ```
- `ksh93`/`bash`:

  ```
  typeset -A map
  map=(
    [A]='{O.O}'
    [a]='{q-p}'
    ...
  )
  s=${map[$c]}
  ```

Portably (with standard `sh` syntax), you could also do:

```
map='|A={O.O}|a={q-p}|...'
s=${map#*"|$c="}
s=${s%%"|"*}
```

(assuming none of the strings contain `|` characters).

Or you could also invoke a proper text-processing utility (use the shell to invoke commands, as that's what it's been designed for and a text processing utility to process text).

```
STRING=whatever awk -F= '{map[$1] = $2}
   END {
     s = ENVIRON["STRING"]
     l = length(s)
     for (i = 1; i <= l; i++) {
       c = substr(s, i, 1)
       print map[c]
     }
   }' << EOF
A={O.O}
a={q-p}
...
EOF
```

(though beware that some implementations of `awk` like `mawk` only support single-byte characters).

Comment: This is not producing the "desired" output as the OP mentions...

Comment: @Rakesh, true, that part being unclear to me, I had initially left that out. See edit though.

Comment: I'm sorry guys if this is confusing. Basically, I want it to echo things from a list of strings based on what letters are typed into `$foo`.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant, mapping text to letters.

Comment: @Terkey-Juice, so does this answer answer your question?

Comment: I'm testing it out as we speak. Don't worry, if it does I'll check the mark

Comment: Apologies if I confused anybody, I've edited my original question so it makes much more sense as to what I want to accomplish.